# Bash script with telnet "connection closed by foreign host"

Tags: bash, telnet

I have a bash script that is supposed to connect with my Sky+HD box and pause it. This is a service supported by the box as it is the same protocol as their iPhone/iPad app.

Is there anything glaringly obvious as to why it wouldn't remain connected?

```
    (echo 'POST /SkyPlay2 HTTP/1.1
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-nds-com:service:SkyPlay:2#SetAVTransportURI"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 399 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-nds-com:service:SkyPlay:2"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><CurrentURI>xsi://'$line'</CurrentURI><CurrentURIMetaData>NOT_IMPLEMENTED</CurrentURIMetaData></u:SetAVTransportURI></s:Body></s:Envelope>') | telnet 192.168.1.82 49153
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your box may have access restrictions that make it disallow connections from the machine you're running the script on.

As general advice:

1. do quote `$line` to prevent nasty things from happening, as in: `echo 'foo'"$list"'bar'` (notice the double quotes);
2. instead of `telnet`, which is meant more for interactive usage, use `nc` (netcat): `echo 'stuff' | nc -n 192.168.1.82 49153`; this may help with your connection issues, if your `telnet` is trying to be smart and negociate telnet protocol specific parameters before it sends your data through;
3. since you only use one command, `echo`, to send data, you don't need to run it in a subshell, so the parentheses `(` `)` are not needed;
4. when you have multiple lines to output, consider using `cat <<EOF` instead of `echo` (look up here-documents in the bash manual)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I understand all but point 1, what should I have quoted that I haven't?

Comment: In the code you pasted, the last line contains `<CurrentURI>xsi://'$line'</CurrentURI>` - the correct form is `<CurrentURI>xsi://'"$line"'</CurrentURI>`

Comment: The nc -n was the issue, it looks like the Sky+HD box doesn't accept telnet (although it used to)